# Rollett stability factor - derivation and numerical meaning

Tags: rf, microwave, network, s-parameters

For two-port networks, a value called the Rollett stability factor, *K*, can be derived, whose value can then be used to assess one of the criteria for the network to be *unconditionally stable* (*K > 1*).

I suppose that only holds whenever both of the stability circles are entirely outside of the unit circle on in the Γ domain - is that correct?

Hence, I wonder:

1. How can it be derived from the expressions for radii and centers of the stability circles (*r<sub>L</sub>*, *c<sub>L</sub>*, *r<sub>S</sub>*, *c<sub>S</sub>*)?
2. What meaning does the value of *K* have, e.g. in the expression for *G<sub>max</sub>*? (from [here](https://www.microwaves101.com/encyclopedias/stability-factor)) - can it be visualized directly?

[image: Formula for maximum gain]

Answer (score -3):

The Rollett stability factor is only applicable for two-port networks and is used to assess one of the criteria for unconditional stability (K > 1) when both stability circles are entirely outside the unit circle in the Γ domain.

To derive the Rollett stability factor, you need the expressions for the radii and centers of the stability circles (rL, cL, rS, cS). The Rollett stability factor is then defined as K = min(rL, rS) / max(rL, rS). This value represents the ratio of the smaller to the larger of the two stability circles, and it provides an indication of the network's stability. If K > 1, the network is considered to be unconditionally stable.

The Rollett stability factor can also be visualized directly as the ratio of the smallest to largest stability circles. The value of K has a direct relationship to the expression for the maximum gain of a two-port network. The formula for the maximum gain, Gmax, is defined as Gmax = 1 / (1 - K^2). The maximum gain represents the highest possible power gain that can be achieved by the two-port network without causing instability. If K > 1, Gmax will always be finite, indicating that the network is unconditionally stable.

Comment: This has been detected as a ChatGPT-generated answer. Further action to follow...